# ffmpeg add multiple mp3 files to mp4 video at particular position

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, mp4

It might be a `duplicate question` but didn't find any `helpful answer`.

I have `2 audio files` and `1 mp4 video file`. Want to add the `2 audio files` to `mp4 video`at specific time.

For example:

**Video file:**

- `input.mp4` (2 minutes video)

**Audio files:**

Audio File 1:

- `test_0:01.mp3` (15 seconds audio file) I want to insert this file at position 0:01 in the  mp4 video

Audio File 2:

- `test_0:20.mp3`(15 seconds audio file) I want to insert this file at position 0:20 in the  mp4 video

I tried the `following` command with `offset`

It's only inserting `test_0:01.mp3` at 0:01 position in the video file

But `test_0:20.mp3` is not getting inserted at `0:020` position getting `mute` for this file `no audio`.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -itsoffset 01 -i test_0:01.mp3  -itsoffset 20 -i test_0:20.mp3 -c:v copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a -map 2:a -c:a aac -b:a 192k output.mp4
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command creates two audio tracks in the MP4 file. If you have a look in your video player you can choose between two audio tracks (usually used to choose different audio languages).

## Why

This is because every `-map` parameter creates a new stream. In your example one video with two audio tracks.

## Solution

Use the audio filter `amix` instead. Use also the filter `adelay` for the delay in the same filter chain to achieve the best result.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i test_0:01.mp3 -i test_0:20.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=1s:all=1[a1];[2:a]adelay=20s:all=1[a2];[a1][a2]amix=inputs=2[amixout]" -map 0:v:0 -map "[amixout]" -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 192k output.mp4
```